# Why CSS files are not producing same results, depending whether they are stored on the web or locally?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to understand a little bit better how the Jquery spinner works.

If I am using the remote CSS file, everything works very well, as you can see in the first screenshot:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

[image]

Now what I did, is to save a local copy of the css file from the address code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css. If I am using this newly created css file, I have no up/down button. Even more strange, the basic up/down function works.

```
<link href="./css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

What am I missing? Many thanks for your hints.

Comment: There are images included with jQuery ui that you need to add to your project in addition to the CSS.

Comment: Should I add that in the <head> part? And how can I do that (if that's possible?)

Comment: I would recommend that you generate a download with all the necessary files and images from here http://jqueryui.com/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI needs some images in addition to the CSS. You can generate a "full package" that includes the CSS and images from here:

http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: Perfect, you made my day. Thanks a lot :)